# GROUP BY datetime in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

how to groupby created_at with a datetime type in codeigniter

this my query

```
public function get_by_filter($filter){

    if ($filter['type_code'] != "") {
        $this->db->where('type_code',$filter['type_code'],'both');
    }

    // if ($filter['from'] != ""  && $filter['until'] != "") {
    //  $this->db->where('created_at >=', $filter['from']);
    //  $this->db->where('created_at <=', $filter['until']);
    // }
    // if ($filter['from'] != "") {
    //  $this->db->where('created_at >=', $filter['from']);
    // }
    // if ($filter['until'] != "") {
    //  $this->db->where('created_at <=', $filter['until']);
    // }

    $this->db->group_by('created_at');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');

    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_payments')->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit query;

try this query

```
public function get_by_filter($filter){



    $this->db->select('id, DATE(created_at) AS dateformated');  // 
    $this->db->group_by('dateformated');
    $q = $this->db->get('tbl_payments');
    $results = $q->result_array();
    return $results;
}
```